# Prevent Angular2 router from showing params in URL

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is it possible to prevent showing the route params in URL?

```
showProfile(customer){
   this.router.navigate(['profile/' + customer.id, customer]);
}
```

Result:

```
http://localhost:3000/profile/10083;id=10083;company=AG...
```

I ask because it crashing my app on reload.

```
Error: Cannot match any routes.
```

**Edit:**

**routing.ts**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/customers', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'profile/:id', component: CustomerProfileComponent },
  { path: 'customers', component: CustomerListComponent },
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Comment: You are using a 'complicated' string into your url, that's probably why it's crashing. You should go with 'simpler' url: /profile/id/123/company/abc etc

Comment: You should show use your routing.ts, so we can look if you've some wrong configurations for the router. It is definitely no solution to hide/show the params if you've this kind of error.

Comment: Thats the route I expect: http://localhost:3000/profile/10083 and the rest ist the customer object which I will pass. There is no need for me to diplay this data.

Comment: @PhilippKief I add routing.ts

Comment: Ok I see the problem, you want to give a complete object to another component by the router/URL. For this use case you should use a resolver [Angular 2 Router Resolver](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard).